# Creating wave effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How might I go about creating a wave pattern like the attached reference?

I was thinking a 'move-copy' approach. But was wondering if there was something simpler. I'm not too familiar with Illustrator so would love some guidance.

What I'm looking for is vertical 2px lines running in a row then the wave effect.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create the stroke unit:

[image: Stroke Unit]

Put a stroke alined at each side of the blue rectangle:

[image: strokes]

Select them and go to menu **Object** > **Blend** > **Make**

Create the *Wave Path*:

[image: wave]

Select the blend ant the *Wave Path* and go to menu **Object** > **Blend** > **Replace Spine**

[image: spine]

Menu **Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options** > **Specified Steps**

[image: steps]

If it is necessary to modify the distance between the sticks, regulate the vector points handles:

[image: drivers]

To replicate the waves make new blends or duplicate the original and transform the *Spine Path* selecting it with the **Direct Selection Tool** + <kbd>Alt</kbd> to get the whole path. In the Gif image it is flipped vertically:

[image: spine transform]

—————————————————————————————————

Once you have all the waves, the recommendation is to put each of them in a different layer and continue working independently.

—————————————————————————————————

To change the strokes length, create the *Cut Path*, or duplicate the *Spine Path* from the next lower blend:

[image: cut path]

Select the blend, menu **Object** > **Blend** > **Expand**

Select the *blend group* together with the *Cut Path* and choose the **Shape Builder Tool**:

[image: shape builder tool]

Pressing  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  delete the excess part of each path and reverse the path direction from the **Stroke Panel**

[image]

Select the sticks, menu **Object** > **Ungroup** 
and **Distribute horizontaly**

[image: distribute]

Comment: WOW. if I could give this a million up votes I would. Thank you so much for spending the time on this. And educating me on the way.